# What is a phone screen?

Tags: human-resources

I'm french and I'm looking for a job in an english-speaking company.
Recently, I received a notification from a contact who is proposing a "phone screen".

What is a phone screen ? How does it differ from a regular phone call ?

Answer (score 5):

"Phone Screen" is HR-speak for a brief telephone interview.  Phone screens are intended to get a brief introduction to a candidate's skills and experience prior to bringing him/her onsite for a more thorough interview.  In essence, the interviewer is "screening out" any candidates that aren't a good fit before devoting time and resources to interviewing them in person.

Answer (score 3):

Phone screen is the initial interview that is conducted over a phone conversation. It usually entails quite a bit of technical or job related questions more than personality based ones. If you give the impression that you are really who you claim to be on your resume, you will be invited (most of the time) to an on-site, in-person interview.